# sum the array according to the repeating index

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a two-row array `A` as follows. I want to sum the elements in the second row when the index in the first row is repeated and eventually produce a matrix `B`.
How can I do it in MATLAB?

```
A = [1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1;
     1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4];

B = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1;
     1, 5, 4, 5, 1, 5, 4];
```

I try to use `diff` function (see below) to figure out the index

```
d = diff(A(1,:))==0
goodIdx = ~([d',false]|[false,d'])
```

but I don't know how to proceed further.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one possible approach:

```
A = [1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1;
     1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4];           % data
ind = [true diff(A(1,:))~=0];              % logical indices of "new" values
s = accumarray(cumsum(ind).', A(2,:).').'; % sum values in second row of A in groups 
                                           % defined by the cumulative sum of ind
B = [A(1,ind); s];                         % build result
```